# Want to merge 2 lines in one and avoid the correct line using end pattern ABC in unix

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have file like below:

```
07-10-2021-ABC-hello-203455
07-10-2021-Aer-hello-2034
55
07-10-2021-Aad-hello-20345
5
07-10-2021-dafC-hello-203
455
```

I want output as below:

```
07-10-2021-ABC-hello-203455
07-10-2021-aer-hello-203455
07-10-2021-Aad-hello-203455
07-10-2021-dafc-hello-203455
```

Can you please helpout with query? I tried using `sed` but didn't work.
I want to skip the correct line and incorrect 2 line need to merge in unix.

Comment: You will also have to specify exactly what the criteria for a "correct" line is.  If we see a line saying `07-10-2021-ABC-hello-203` followed by another line saying `07-10-2021-aer-hello-20`, are one or both possibly correct? Should a correct line always have a specific number of dash-delimited fields, or should they always start with `07`, or contain the string `hello-203455`?

Answer (score 2):

I got to this solution<sup>1</sup> using `sed` plus `awk`:

```bsh
$ sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)$/#\1/' file | awk -v RS= '{ gsub(/\n#/, "", $0); print }'
07-10-2021-ABC-hello-203455
07-10-2021-Aer-hello-203455
07-10-2021-Aad-hello-203455
07-10-2021-dafC-hello-203455
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I'm sure it can be done with just `sed` *or* `awk`, but so far I couldn't make it work.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='[0-9]{2}(-[^-]*){5}\n' '
    { print gensub(/\n/,"","g",RT) }
' file
07-10-2021-ABC-hello-203455
07-10-2021-Aer-hello-203455
07-10-2021-Aad-hello-203455
07-10-2021-dafC-hello-203455
```

otherwise with any awk:

```
$ awk '
    /^([0-9]{2}-){2}[0-9]{4}-/ {
        printf "%s%s", prev, $0
        prev = ORS
        next
    }
    { prev = $0 ORS }
    END {
        printf "%s", prev
    }
' file
07-10-2021-ABC-hello-203455
07-10-2021-Aer-hello-203455
07-10-2021-Aad-hello-203455
07-10-2021-dafC-hello-203455
```

Comment: +1 Using this pattern for determining the start of a valid line is much better than `/hello/`, which I used in my answer. Nice trick with the `prev = ORS` too.

Answer (score 0):

Here one way to do it using awk. This assumes that the 'correct' lines are the ones containing the string `hello`. If the criterion is different just change the regular expression `/hello/` to something else like `/-/` or `length($0) > 10` or whatever you need:

```bsh
$ awk '/hello/&&prev{print prev}/hello/{prev=$0;next}{prev=prev $0}END{if(prev)print prev}' file
07-10-2021-ABC-hello-203455
07-10-2021-Aer-hello-203455
07-10-2021-Aad-hello-203455
07-10-2021-dafC-hello-203455
```

In a more readable format:

```c
awk '
  /hello/ && prev {print prev}
  /hello/ {prev = $0; next}
  {prev = prev $0}
  END {if (prev) print prev}
' file
```

Another test with more broken file:

```bsh
$ cat file2
07-10-2021-ABC-hello-203455
07-10-2021-ABC-hello-203455
07-10-2021-ABC-hello-203455
07-10-2021-Aer-hello-2034
55
111
07-10-2021-Aad-hello-20345
07-10-2021-Aad-hello-20345
07-10-2021-Aad-hello-20345
5
07-10-2021-dafC-hello-203
455
07-10-2021-dafC-hello-203

$ awk '
  /hello/ && prev {print prev}
  /hello/ {prev = $0; next}
  {prev = prev $0}
  END {if (prev) print prev}' file2
07-10-2021-ABC-hello-203455
07-10-2021-ABC-hello-203455
07-10-2021-ABC-hello-203455
07-10-2021-Aer-hello-203455111
07-10-2021-Aad-hello-20345
07-10-2021-Aad-hello-20345
07-10-2021-Aad-hello-203455
07-10-2021-dafC-hello-203455
07-10-2021-dafC-hello-203
```

Comment: It will break if a line is broken within the `hello` string.

Comment: @they: Yes I not really sure what defines a line as broken and what as not borken, It could be helpful if OP made the criterion more clear, and also added some more examples.

Comment: The start of each line seems to be a date on some format. Maybe we could use that. I'm looking at a `sed` solution at the moment, that I might possibly post if it turns into something.

Answer (score -3):

First of all this output can be generated by command if you have "hello" in all correct lines

```
cat YourFile | grep hello
```

If you want to list incorrect lines and merge them to 1 line use this to show them delimited by ","

```
cat YourFile | grep -v hello | paste -s -d, -
```

Output after this command is

```
55,5,455
```

Comment: My fault. I didn't understand that strings are splited in input file.